# Show vs ShowDialog issues with both

Tags: c#, winforms

I have been writing a little application where Form1 opens, checks that a config file is present and correct, and then hides in the Task Bar until an API call is received.

When this happens I would like a new Form to open in the bottom right corner and show various details, but am having some issues. When I use ShowDialog to open the form the form doesn't always honor the TopMost to try and get the form to appear on top of *all other windows*, however if I use Show instead, this honors the TopMost, but the form style is *messed up* as can be seen below.

The standard form looks like:

```
Caller Number: XXXXXXXX
Caller Name:   XXXXXXXX
               XXXXXXXX
```

**Code Examples**

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.TopMost = true;
form2.TopLevel = true;
form2.ShowDialog();
```

Above: Doesn't always open on-top of everything

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.TopMost = true;
form2.TopLevel = true;
form2.Show();
```

My Current code is:

```
private void checkCalls(object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    var client = new RestClient("http://apiurl.com");
    client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(api_username, api_password);

    var request = new RestRequest("/", Method.GET);

    // async with deserialization
    var asyncHandle = client.ExecuteAsync<Call>(request, response =>
    {
        if (response.Data == null)
        {
            if (incoming_call == true && notify_type == "Pop-Up")
            {
                if (caller.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    caller.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate {
                        Console.WriteLine("Hidden via Invoke");
                        caller.Hide();
                    }));
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Hidden without Invoke");
                    caller.Hide();
                }
            }
            incoming_call = false;
        }
        else if(incoming_call == false)
        {
            incoming_call = true;
            if (notify_type == "Pop-Up")
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Openning Window");
                if (caller.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    caller.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Opening Window via Invoke");
                        caller.Show();
                        caller.TopMost = true;
                        caller.TopLevel = true;
                    }));
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Opening Window");
                    caller.Show();
                    caller.TopMost = true;
                    caller.TopLevel = true;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And some Logs:

```
Opening Window
Hidden without Invoke
Opening Window
Hidden without Invoke
```

Above, opens like (hard to see, but the Text Boxes should be greyed out as Disabled and Readonly, and there is black text next to each Text Field which is now invisible, but has a white background):

[screenshot http://img546.imageshack.us/img546/5517/screenshot20120708at222.png](http://img546.imageshack.us/img546/5517/screenshot20120708at222.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is not clear, flesh it out a bit more. You explained what happens, but not **why** it's incorrect. What is happening vs. what you expect to happen.

Comment: @SergioTapia Sorry, hopefully the edits I have just made will assist a bit more

Comment: How are you hiding the form in your code?

Comment: I have an one question! What is textBox3 do ? :)

Comment: What happens if you delete the TopLevel = true?

Comment: @LostInLib this contains the Callers Name if a DB lookup found them

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata form2.Hide(); however this happens even on the first instance that I spawn the object form2

Comment: @MattClements: Please just update your question with the full code showing your hiding and calling the form. This already seems like an API compatibility problem to me, have you tried changing the black text to blue for instance to see what happens?

Comment: @AmiramKorach No difference i'm afraid - still the same issue

Comment: @MattClements: You didn't show where you declared the caller object, however, change the type of form to FixedDialog. If problem persists, try changing your `caller.Hide()` to `Caller.SetOpacity(0)`, and your `caller.Show()` to `.SetOpacity(1)`. Force a refresh of the control after Each `Set.Opacity` Good luck

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata - You nailed it! Looked though everything that you had put and tried one by one. Finally I saw "Force a refresh of the control after Each Set.Opacity" and realised that I needed to caller.Refresh(); after showing the form, and setting TopMost/TopLevel! Could you possibly add this as an answer and I will accept and upvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the type of form to FixedDialog. If problem persists, try changing your `caller.Hide()` to `caller.SetOpacity(0)`, and your `caller.Show()` to `caller.SetOpacity(1)`

Force a refresh of the form whenever you show the form.

Comment: You nailed it! Looked though everything that you had put and tried one by one. Finally I saw "Force a refresh of the control after Each Set.Opacity" and realised that I needed to caller.Refresh(); after showing the form, and setting TopMost/TopLevel!